# Core Data read and write sequence

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm coding iOS 6.1 and learning Core Data.

If I have a Core Data entity/object in memory and I write it out, can I continue to hold a copy in memory, update it and write it out again?

Or, once I've written it out, do I have to read it in again to update it and then write it out again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know already, Core Data uses both a **persistent store** and a **managed object context**. Data is loaded and saved using the managed object context.

The answer to your first question is **yes**. As long as your local reference variable is still in scope, you are able to update/save the content of the variable as many times as you want; remember, though, that it won't save to your back end unless you explicitly save your managed object context: `[NSManagedObjectContext save:(NSError*)error]`.

Once that reference variable has gone out of scope, you'll need to fetch the managed object again if you want to edit it in any way.